# Change size of JButton and text of a label on focus Gain and lost event of JButton

Tags: java, swing, focus, jbutton, jlabel

I want to increase and decrease the size of `JButton` on its focus gain and lost event. Simultaneously I want to change the `JLabel` with the text of focussed `JButton`.

If I'm not changing the `JLabel` text, I'm able to change the size of buttons, but when I'm changing the label simultaneously the size of `JButton` does not change.

Here is the code:

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements FocusListener {

    JButton b1, b2;
    JLabel lbl;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Main() {

        setSize(600, 600);//Size of JFrame
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);//Sets if its visible.

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        b1 = new JButton("Start");//The JButton name.
        b1.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        b1.addFocusListener(this);
        panel.add(b1);

        b2 = new JButton("End");//The JButton name.
        b2.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        b2.addFocusListener(this);

        panel.add(b2);

        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        lbl = new JLabel("       ");
        add(lbl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();//Reads method main()
    }

    /*
    * What the button does.
    */
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent ae) {

        if (ae.getSource() == b2) {
            b2.setSize(55, 26);
        } else if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
            b1.setSize(55, 26);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent ae) {

        if (ae.getSource() == b2) {
            lbl.setText("End");
            b2.setSize(55, 40);
        } else if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
            lbl.setText("Start");
            b1.setSize(55, 40);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing absolute-layout (or null-layout) with an implicit LayoutManager (JPanel comes with a FlowLayout by default).

When you call setText on a JLabel (and that text changes), it automatically calls revalidate which will eventually trigger the LayoutManager to lay out the components.

Either use a LayoutManager, optionally set some constraints and pref/min/max size (but the latter is not recommended) (and you never call setLocation/setSize/setBounds), or use null-layout and set yourself the location and size of the components (and in this case you must call yourself setSize/setLocation/setBounds).

Seriously consider reading the [LayoutManager tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). There is a dedicated chapter on "*Doing Without a Layout Manager (Absolute Positioning)*".

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements FocusListener {

JButton b1, b2;
JLabel lbl;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Main() {

    setSize(600, 600);// Size of JFrame
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);// Sets if its visible.

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setSize(this.getSize());
    b1 = new JButton("Start");// The JButton name.
    b1.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    b1.addFocusListener(this);
    b1.setLocation(10, 12);
    panel.add(b1);

    b2 = new JButton("End");// The JButton name.
    b2.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    b2.addFocusListener(this);
    b2.setLocation(70, 12);
    panel.add(b2);

    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    lbl = new JLabel("       ");
    add(lbl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();// Reads method main()
}

/*
 * What the button does.
 */
@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent ae) {

    if (ae.getSource() == b2) {
        b2.setSize(55, 26);
    } else if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
        b1.setSize(55, 26);
    }

}

@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent ae) {

    if (ae.getSource() == b2) {
        lbl.setText("End");
        b2.setSize(55, 40);
    } else if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
        lbl.setText("Start");
        b1.setSize(55, 40);
    }

}
}
```